# Resultado inesperado em programa em C

Tags: c, variáveis, compilação, auto-incremento

Nesse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
int x, y = 10;
//incrementa depois atribui
y = ++x;
printf("x = %d\n", x);
printf("y = %d\n", y);
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Compilado e executado no codeblocks ele retorna o tamanho da variavel mais o incremento;
O resultado deveria ser x = 11; e y = 11;
No ideone ele retorna x e y = 1;
A diferença entre x++; e ++x; é que x++ = 10 + 1 e ++x = 1 + 10?

Comment: Boa pergunta: tem codigo, tem o resultado esperado, tem o resultado obtido.

Comment: Não te entendi pmg?

Comment: user ... muitos utilizadores fazem perguntas a que é dificil responder: a tua pergunta é eficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não esta iniciando a variável x

aqui:

```
int x, y = 10;
```

deveria ser

```
int x = 10, y = 10;
```

Comment: Sim mas fiz como no livro.

Comment: então ou o livro está errado ou você leu errado.